# Laravel Chaining Jobs to Different Queues

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to chain two jobs to a different queue? I have two outgoing API calls via guzzle which I'm attempting to run concurrently, and one Job (Abstracts) depends on the first Job (DOI) to be completed. This is my current "job chaining" command which works okay, however it only sends them to the journals queue. What I would like is to send the Abstracts job to a separate queue with its own workers.

`ProcessDois::withChain([
                    new ProcessAbstract($item->DOI),
                ])->dispatch($item->DOI, $this->journal)->onConnection('redis')->onQueue('journals');`

Ideally I want something like

`ProcessDois::withChain([
                    new ProcessAbstract($item->DOI)>onQueue('abstracts')->onConnection('redis',
                ])->dispatch($item->DOI, $this->journal)->onConnection('redis')->onQueue('journals');`